# Java If statement Array Address

Tags: java

I have a code that will give me the coordinates of certain points in an array using user input. What code would I add to make the code output say that the address could not be found if the number in the array is not there? I'm pretty sure I need an else statement but I can't get it to work. Here is the code I have right now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabActivityArray 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in); 
        int rows; 
        int columns;
        int check1,check2;

        System.out.println("Enter number of rows: "); 

        rows = scanner.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println ("Now enter the number of columns: "); 

        columns = scanner.nextInt(); 

        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns]; 

        System.out.println("Enter the number to start the array: ");

        int value = scanner.nextInt(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                array[i][j]=value++;
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "   " ); 
            }    
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Please give one integer value to be checked in the array: "); 
        check1 = scanner.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println ("Please give a second integer value to be checked in the array: "); 

        check2 = scanner.nextInt(); 

        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) 
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < columns; ++j ) 
            {
                if ( array[i][j] == check1 ) 
                {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " is located at address array[" + i + "," + j + "]");       
                }
                if ( array[i][j] == check2 ) 
                {
                    System.out.print("\n" + array[i][j] + " is located at address array[" + i + "," + j + "]");
                    System.out.println(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Initialize a `Flag` variable to `False` and then look for the number in the array. If found set `FLag = True`. After the loop check the `Flag`. If it is still `False` then you haven't found the number, if it is `True` you have.

Comment: where is your code. Don't remove your code and also accept someones answer from below. Otherwise this questions doesn't make any sense the way it is now.

Comment: -1 for removing the question. Edit your post to show us the question and I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

**step 1:**  make a flag say

```
boolean check1Found = false;
```

**step 2:**  if you find the value, set the flag to `true`

```
if ( array[i][j] == check1 ) 
{
    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " is located at address array[" + i + "," + j + "]"); 
    check1Found = true;     
}
```

**step 3:** after your loop is finished, print a message if that flag is still `false`

```
if(check1Found == false)
{
    System.out.println("check 1 not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add two `bool` flag which are false at first but when the numbers youre searching are found, they are set to true.

```
 bool foundFlag1 = false;
 bool foundFlag2 = false;
```

Then

```
if ( array[i][j] == check2 ) {
    foundFlag2 = true;
    ..
}
```

and do the same for `check1`.

If the flags are false, you know that you couldn't find those inputs!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right here. Here is the Pseudocode

> 1. Initialize `Boolean Flag = false;`
> 2. Search for number in `array`. if found set `Flag = True`.
> 3. After searching the number in `array`, check `Flag`.
> 4. If `Flag = False`, print "the address could not be found"

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
boolean check1Flag = false;
boolean check2Flag = false;
for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < columns; ++j )
    {
        if ( array[i][j] == check1 ) 
        {
            System.out.println(array[i][j] + " is located at address array[" + i + "," + j + "]");       
             check1Flag = true;               
        }
        if ( array[i][j] == check2 ) 
        {
             System.out.println(array[i][j] + " is located at address array[" + i + "," + j + "]");
             check2Flag = true;
        }


     }
}
if(!check1Flag)
{
    System.out.println("Can't find " + check1);
}
if(!check2Flag)
{
    System.out.println("Can't find " + check2);
}
```

The flags are set to true when the array is found, so if either are false than that address could not be found.